# Removing duplicate code in rspec tests with fixtures

Tags: ruby, rspec

I use Rspec and fixtures to test Rails models.

A few test cases have very similar code which looks like this

```
it 'creates request' do
  u = users(:user_one)
  o = documents(:document_one)
  requests = Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: u, document: o) 
  expect { o.request_access(u) }.to change { requests.count }.by(1)    
end

it 'does not create a request if user already has access' do
  u = users(:user_one)
  o = documents(:document_one)
  Request.create status: Request::ACCEPTED, user: u, document: 0
  requests = Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: u, document: o) 
  expect { o.request_access(u) }.not_to change { requests.count }    
end
```

How could I eliminate code duplication here? Is there a way to use `let` to solve the problem? What if I have more test cases where other fixtures are used and hence `Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: u, document: o)` refers to other objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be DRY enough. `let` all the things!

```
let(:user) { users(:user_one) }
let(:document) { documents(:document_one) }
let(:requests) { Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: user, document: document) }
let(:action) { document.request_access(user) }

context 'user does not have access' do
  it 'creates request' do
    expect { action }.to change { requests.count }.by(1)    
  end
end

context 'user has approved access' do
  before do 
    Request.create status: Request::ACCEPTED, user: user, document: document
  end

  it 'does not create a request' do
    expect { action }.not_to change { requests.count }    
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, thanks. For some reason I believed that you can not use `let` blocks in other `let` blocks. Also wouldn't it be more clear to use `subject` for `:action`?

Comment: @S.S.J: don't know. Never liked `subject`. Besides, it implies some object, whereas here we have an action. But name it whatever you want. :)

Comment: Styles differ, but using an explicit `subject` is generally discouraged unless you are writing a shared method. Ideally the subject should be obvious from reading the test.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `let` or `before(:each)`:

```
before(:each) do
  @u = users(:user_one)
  @o = documents(:document_one)
end

it 'creates request' do
  requests = Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: @u, document: @o) 
  expect { @o.request_access(@u) }.to change { requests.count }.by(1)    
end

it 'does not create a request if user already has access' do
  Request.create status: Request::ACCEPTED, user: @u, document: @o
  requests = Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: @u, document: @o) 
  expect { @o.request_access(@u) }.not_to change { requests.count }    
end
```

---

```
let(:u) { users(:user_one) }
let(:o) { documents(:document_one) }

it 'creates request' do
  requests = Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: u, document: o) 
  expect { o.request_access(u) }.to change { requests.count }.by(1)    
end

it 'does not create a request if user already has access' do
  Request.create status: Request::ACCEPTED, user: u, document: o
  requests = Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: u, document: o) 
  expect { o.request_access(u) }.not_to change { requests.count }    
end
```

---

**EDIT**: You can't add the `requests` query to a before filter because you have a `Request.create` before your query in the second test. Anyway, to DRY it you could create a method that returns the query:

```
let(:u) { users(:user_one) }
let(:o) { documents(:document_one) }

it 'creates request' do
  requests 
  expect { o.request_access(u) }.to change { requests.count }.by(1)    
end

it 'does not create a request if user already has access' do
  Request.create status: Request::ACCEPTED, user: u, document: o
  requests 
  expect { o.request_access(u) }.not_to change { requests.count }    
end

def requests
  Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: u, document: o)
end
```

Comment: I would really like to remove `requests = Request.where(status: Request::PENDING, user: u, document: o)` too. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: the problem is the `Request.create` that you need to call before the requests query, so you can't add it to a `before(:each)`... please note my edited answer

Comment: if you have the `Request.create` in a before action it would run in both tests. So, your first test would fail unless you wrap the tests in contexts like Sergio answer